# Alternative to nested loops

Tags: java

I wrote these method for my program and i felt that it is hard to read as there are too many loops, is there any other alternative to this code to make it look cleaner and easier to read

```
public static void printRoutingTable(Map <Node, List<Edge>> adj, Node Root)
{
    for (Node thisNode : adj.keySet())
    {   
        Node currentNode = thisNode;
        String nextHop;             
        if(currentNode.getParent() != null){
            do{
                if(currentNode.getParent() != Root){
                    currentNode = currentNode.getParent();
                    nextHop =  currentNode.getAddr();
                }
                else{
                   nextHop = currentNode.getAddr() ;
                }       
            }
            while(currentNode.getParent() != Root);
        }
        else
        {
            nextHop = ""+currentNode.getAddr();
        }
        nextHop = nextHop.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better suited to [codereview.se], if it works.

Comment: Note that there are only two loops here: a for loop and a do...while loop. `if` is not a loop.

Comment: The inner do loop looks like it can be simplified to `while (currentNode.getParent() != Root) { currentNode = currentNode.getParent(); } nextHop = currentNode.getAddr();`.

Comment: For a method claiming to print something, there's not a whole lot of printing going on. Unless these getters have side effects, the whole loop body could just be removed.

Comment: When you will evolve more into coding, Cyclomatic Complexity: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/cyclomatic_complexity.htm is a concept you will begin to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried, but this should be a functional and recursive version of your code.

```
String getNextAddr(Node node, StringBuilder sb, Node root) {
    sb.add(node.getAddr());
    if (node.getParent() != null && node.getParent() != root) {
      return getNextAddr(node.getParent(), sb);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

String nextHopList = 
  adj.keySet()
    .stream()
    .map(k -> getNextAddr(k, new StringBuilder(), Root))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what your code is trying to achieve. At the moment it's not actually doing anything because the `nextHop` variable is local and nothing seems to be accumulated in the loop. I'm assuming you intend to join the strings your are generating.

- there's no point passing in a map if you aren't going to use it. Better to pass a collection (or, better, `Stream`) of nodes.
- generally the root node is the only one with a null parent. So it's likely you also don't need to pass in a reference to the root node.
- if parent is optional I suggest you return `Optional<Node>` from `getParent` rather than `Node`.
- an easy way to make the code easier to read is to break the parts into separate methods that are named after exactly what they do.

So taking these suggestions into account, something like the following:

```
String getRoutingTable(Stream<Node> nodes) {
    return nodes
        .flatMap(this::getRoutingForNode)
        .map(Node::getAddr)
        .collect(joining(";"));
}

private Stream<Node> getRoutingForNode(Node node) {
    Stream.Builder<Node> pathToRoot = Stream.builder();
    for (Node c = node; c.getParent().isPresent(); c = node.getParent().get()) {
        pathToRoot.accept(c);
    }
    return pathToRoot.build();
}
```

Note that in Java 9 the `getRoutingForNode` will become much more readable as you will be able to dispense with the `Builder`:

```
return Stream.iterate(node, 
    n -> node.getParent().isPresent(), 
    n -> n.getParent().get());
```